# Writing doctests for pyramid web app which depend on settings in ini file

Tags: python, pyramid, wsgi, webtest

I would like to write doctests for my pyramid web app, using the [webtest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/) module. I tried it like this:

```
from my_webapp import main
from webtest import TestApp

app = TestApp(main({}))
result = app.get('/')
```

This raises a `KeyError` (because `some.url` is not known) when my code reaches this line:

```
url = request.registry.settings['some.url']
```

The value of `some.url` is specified in the paster ini file of my application. Is there a simple way to use my `development.ini` when running my test code? I did not yet fully understand how/when the ini file is loaded during pyramid start up, so it's hard to figure out where to load it while testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main` is invoked with the contents of your ini file. A simple way to load your app from an ini is:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app

app = get_app('testing.ini#main')
test_app = TestApp(app)
```

This expects "testing.ini" to be in the current working directory, so you may need to tweak that. If you'd like it to be relative to a spot in your tree you can use:

```
import os.path
import some_module

here = os.path.dirname(some_module.__file__)
app = get_app(os.path.join(here, 'testing.ini'))
```